# Trying to visualize statistical report from google analytics. But It doesn't work. Help needed

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

This is the code I used. I want to visualize the data from the google analytics onto my website. This is a demo page with absolutely no content. I am trying to test it with this and then implement on my website. I request someone to correct me if I'm getting it wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#share-buttons img {
width: 35px;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}

</style>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});

</script>
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
<p>This is a test page</p>
<script>

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'clientId',
  });


  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
  });

  // Render the view selector to the page.
  viewSelector.execute();


  /**
   * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
   * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
   * with the id "chart-container".
   */
  var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });


  /**
   * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
   */
  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
  });

});
</script>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=&text= My Results &hashtags=UMCProteinServer" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The actual question is missing.

Comment: There is an error elsewhere, which I am unable to find. I thought anyone would do me a favor by pointing it out?